# Subquery using SELECT ADODB Excel Not Working (VBA)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to select data from other table using subquery in ADODB Excel. Here is my code:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim cmd As String
    If OpenConnection() = True Then 'The connection function already created in my module
        cmd = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT [SheetName] FROM `Breakdown structure library$` WHERE [Name (Name *)]='WBS');"
        Rcdset.Open cmd, Con, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
        With shTemp
            .Cells.Delete
            .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Rcdset
        End With
        If Con.State Then Con.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

The result is error :

> *Run-time error '-2147217904' (80040e10): No value given for one or more parameters*

I know what's going on. You have to add '$' at the end of the sheet name to execute query in ADODB Excel such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` '(not working in ADODB Excel, but working in Access database)
SELECT * FROM `MyTable$` '(working in ADODB Excel)
```

I don't know how to make sql subquery to identify the table automaticaly, where we are going to select the data.

Comment: Are you trying to get the result from the sub-select as the table name in the select ?

Comment: @NoChance : The result is name of the table when I execute it separately.

Comment: @CDP1802 : Yes! That is what I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a sub-select to determine the table name of the select, use 2 queries.

```vb
    Dim sTableName As String, SQL As String, rcdset As New ADODB.Recordset
    If OpenConnection() = True Then 'The connection function already created in my module
      
        SQL = " SELECT [SheetName] " & _
              " FROM `Breakdown structure library$` " & _
              " WHERE [Name (Name *)]='WBS';"
        sTableName = con.Execute(SQL)(0)

        SQL = " SELECT * FROM [" & sTableName & "$]"
        rcdset.Open SQL, con, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
        With shTemp
            .Cells.Delete
            .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rcdset
        End With
        If con.State Then con.Close
     
     End If
```